# How to reuse service definitions in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

service-docker-compose.yml contains definitions for ServiceA, ServiceB
web-docker-compose.yml contains definitions for ServiceC but needs to reuse definitions from service-docker-compose.yml. I would prefer not to copy over the definitions and the environment variables, how should I manage this